A doubt on Proofs-of-Sequential-Work protocols
Proofs-of-Sequential-Work ($\mathsf{PoSW}$) are cryptographic protocols that engage two parties, a prover with $\mathtt{poly}(N)$-parallel processors and a deterministic verifier such that the verifier can check in $\mathcal{O}(\log{N})$-time if the prover has spent $\Omega(N)$-parallel time to compute an inherently sequential function. Some well-known examples (that are not verifiable delay functions) are,

Simple Proofs of Sequential Work
Incremental Proofs of Sequential Work
Reversible Proofs of Sequential Work

Ref. [1,2] and Ref.3 exploit the inherent sequentiality of random oracles and random permutation oracles, respectively, in their design.
But, Theorem 3.6 in the following paper refutes the existence of $\mathsf{PoSW}$s in the random oracle model and the authors extend the same for the random permutation oracle in Sect. 4.3.,
Can Verifiable Delay Functions be Based on Random Oracles?
I am unable to understand the actual implication of Theorem 3.6. So, my question is does Theorem 3.6 and Sect. 4.3 refute the $\mathsf{PoSW}$s in Ref. [1,2,3]?

Hi Somudro and welcome. Not sure why your questions are apparently flying below most people's radar. Maybe it is just a subject where the community lacks experts. Voted up the question to let it gain a bit more attention.

@MaartenBodewes Thank you so much for both the upvotes. I really want to comment on different posts which I can not yet. Also, I apologise for this delayed reply. To be honest, I thought my questions were not clear enough to answer :) Meanwhile both the questions have been resolved.

I would like to post the answer recieved in a personal commmunication by the author of the Theorem 3.6.
Theorem 3.6 only rules out tight proofs-of-sequential-work in the random oracle model. The constructions in Refs. [1,2,3] are not tight, and thus, would not be captured by its lower bound.
A proofs-of-sequential-work is tight if it can be computed honestly in time $N$ but not  in parallel time $\sigma(N)<N-o(N)$.
